# Remaping "Calc", "Mail" and "Home" Keys in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard

I have a Cherry Bluetooth keyboard that includes special keys for a calculator, mail, home/myPC. I want to remap them to multimedia keys, but fail to do so.
I used `xbindkeys`, which identifies them as `XF86Calculator`, `XF86Mail` and `XF86HomePage` respectively. 
However, binding them to `X86AudioNext`, `X86AudioPlay` and `X86AudioPrev` has no effect.

I checked the `xev` output:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6e00001,
    root 0xe8, subw 0x0, time 7101116, (580,268), root:(3094,1340),
    state 0x10, keycode 148 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:                            
    XFilterEvent returns: False


KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6e00001,
    root 0xe8, subw 0x0, time 7101620, (580,268), root:(3094,1340),
    state 0x10, keycode 158 (keysym 0x1008ff2e, XF86WWW), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6e00001,
    root 0xe8, subw 0x0, time 7101812, (580,268), root:(3094,1340),
    state 0x10, keycode 180 (keysym 0x1008ff18, XF86HomePage), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

With that, I tried to create an `.Xmodmap` file with

```
keycode 148 = XF86AudioPrev
keycode 158 = XF86AudioPlay
keycode 180 = XF86AudioNext
```

But `xmodmap .Xmodmap` again didn't have any effect.

I then checked `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/xfree86` alternative key-symbols, and changed /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc accordingly and restarted the `xkb` profile.

```
key <I14>  {    [ XF86AudioPrev ]   };
key <I1E>  {    [ XF86AudioPlay ]   };
key <I78>  {    [ XF86AudioNext ]   };
```

Any idea what else to do?

---

After a day of fiddling, I find the first two keys for calculator and mail working as media keys, while home/myPC is still unresponsive.
for the functioning keys, `xev` gives this response

```
FocusIn event, serial 50, synthetic NO, window 0x6c00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 50, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

To add to the confusion, the not-working myPC key returns four events in `xev`, for two different keycodes, plus a new line `XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 171`

My current workaround is to use `ctrl + myPC`. This works well in xbindkeys.

---

Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Kernel: 4.9.0-6-amd64

Xfce4

Comment: Does your multimedia player support these special keys?

Comment: Yes, I use these key bindings successfully with Rhythmbox on other keyboards.

Comment: After loading your `.Xmodmap`, can you verify with `xmodmap -pke` that the bindings are effective? Are the keycodes also used for something else? Did you check with `xev` whether they have "no effect"? Anything suspicious in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`?

Comment: All the bindings are assigned to the respective keycodes. `xev` shows either `XF86AudioNext`  or a KeymapNotify event.

Comment: The `FocusIn` (and probably preceding `FocusOut`) event shows some other application is stealing the keypress. Prime suspects are your window manager, input method helpers or parts of your desktop, though we had one case where Skype was the culprit... You can also try mapping it to a different keysym (which is hopefully not stolen)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend my project: [KeyRemapper](https://github.com/chilauhe/KeyRemapper), it's easy to use and straightforward.

My Ctrl key is not working, so I wrote this, LOL